# SQL Syntax error in Insert and Select nested Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$FullName = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
$EmailAdd = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email_address']);
$City = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['city']);
$State = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['state']);

$SqlEInsert= "INSERT INTO `td_email` VALUES ((SELECT ownerid FROM 'td_events' where event_id = '$EvID'),'$EmailAdd','$FullName', '$City'  ,'$State')";

$RsEmail = mysql_query($SqlEInsert) or die('Error :' . mysql_error());
```

but I'm getting the following error when I run the application

> Error :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''td_events' where event_id = '394'),'email@hotmail.com','Full Name', 'Atl' at line 1

Comment: Why not select the values first, then insert them? You're trying too much with that query.

Comment: Change `'td_events'` to `\`td_events\``

Comment: Please use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php); **The MySQL extension is deprecated and should no longer be used.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need **'** for the table name when you want to use quotes then you have to use **`**

```
$SqlEInsert= "INSERT INTO td_email VALUES ((SELECT ownerid FROM td_events WHERE event_id = '$EvID'),'$EmailAdd','$FullName', '$City'  ,'$State')";
```

And please take a look at SQL Injections and Security

```
$SqlEInsert= "INSERT INTO td_email VALUES ((SELECT ownerid FROM td_events WHERE event_id = '".(int)$EvID."'),'".mysql_real_escape_string($EmailAdd)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($FullName)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($City)."'  ,'".mysql_real_escape_string($State)."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

The `td_event` is a field name rather than a value. Escape it with an apostrophe.

```
$SqlEInsert= "INSERT INTO `td_email` VALUES ((SELECT ownerid FROM `td_events` where event_id = '$EvID'),'$EmailAdd','$FullName', '$City'  ,'$State')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your values are escaped. You can run them through: `mysql_real_escape_string()` to do so.